# Cannot open source file "mosquitto.h"C/C++(1696)

Tags: c, mosquitto, raspberry-pi-pico, libmosquitto

I am trying to include mosquitto.h into my project. I installed mosquitto from "mosquitto-2.0.18-install-windows-x64" installer to C:\Program Files\mosquitto\devel.
It seems like I have to add that address to somewhere but I dont have any clear idea where to.
When i build the program, i got this error:

```
[build] D:\RP_Pico_W_mqtt_test\RP_Pico_W_2_mqtt\main2.c:3:10: fatal error: mosquitto.h: No such file or directory
[build]     3 | #include <mosquitto.h>
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\main2.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/main2.dir/main2.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1509: CMakeFiles/main2.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

And I wrote a simple code with raspberry pi pico w:

```
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"
#include <mosquitto.h>

int main() 
{
    stdio_init_all();
    if (cyw43_arch_init()) 
    {
        printf("Wi-Fi init failed");
        return -1;
    }
    while (true) 
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to all these Cmake, VScode and Pico w. Please help me!

Comment: and this is my current CMakeList.txt, hope someone can help me:
"cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(PICO_BOARD pico_w)
#include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
include($ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH}/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake)
project(main2 C CXX ASM)
pico_sdk_init()
add_executable(main2 main2.c)  # externalLib/MFRC522.cpp)

#target_include_directories(main PRIVATE externalLib)

target_link_libraries(main2 pico_stdlib pico_cyw43_arch_none hardware_spi)  #add hardware_spi
pico_add_extra_outputs(main2)"

Comment: There are two steps required. First, you need to tell CMake where the mosquitto lib is located. This can be done in several ways, `find_package` being the most common. Then you need to link your library to your target using `target_link_libraries`. However, if you don't really have any need for different build setups, you can also have cmake pass configurations directly to the compiler. For gcc, one would use the `-l`, `-I`, and `-L` options.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78242405/edit) there question rather than getting to add code/config files in comments

Comment: I would be very surprised if the mosquitto MQTT client library will run in the Pico, you probably want to be using the paho-c library

Answer (score 0):

u need to add -I"C:\Program Files\mosquitto\devel" parameters to your compile command.

Comment: can you tell me more about how can i do that? i have to admit that i had no idea, i have just added this to cmakelists:
include_directories("C:/Program Files/mosquitto/devel")
target_link_libraries(main2 pico_stdlib mosquitto) 
but it said: arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmosquitto: No such file or directory

Comment: that depends on your build system, if u use cmake, pls show more about CMakeLists.txt